# What's the best way to implement an application server for smartphone app?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I intend to write a multi platform smartphone app (currently only I-phone and android).
Which has to send and recieve information from a web server I intend to create.
The web server will do all the algorithms, and handles also DB connection.
My question, is how is this best accomplished, which kind of web-server technology fit best the scenario, and supports connections from various devices.

Basically, I thought about implementing a simple TCP/IP protocol, making the app (on the phone) the client, and server on the web on the other side. however, I want to deploy the application to an application server (maybe google app, JBOSS, etc.) and I don't want to be stopped by various firewalls.

does anyone has an idea ?

edit: few things are certain, the application server will be written in java, and db will be mysql.

Comment: What kind of data are you going to process? What kind of app is this going to be? The more details you can give us, the more specific we can be in our recommendations.

Comment: the data is pretty simple, only requests and responds with primitive types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very broad question and any suggestion about which backend technology to use will depend on your language preferences, your other requirements, etc.

For starters, I'd suggest JSON over HTTP as a transport mechanism: it's easy to parse on both client and server-side, and it's directly usable in Javascript should the need arise.  XML is another choice, but it can be annoying to parse.

JSON-over-HTTP (or XML) will be completely device agnostic and won't have the firewall/proxy problems you'll run into trying to do a custom-implemented TCP-based protocol.

For the backend, may folks use MySQL or Postgres for their database, and connect to it from Java, C#, Ruby, PHP, or other server-side languages.  Use what you're comfortable with or what you want to learn next.

Comment: Is Python good for server ? if it is , which module is appropriate ? (django ,flask or ...)

Answer (score 1):

Why not write the server-side as a regular web application - in whatever technology you like (php, asp.net, java)?  This way you can deploy the app on any web server and your client apps on the phones would simply establish a connection to an HTTP server.  Normally, firewalls would not be a problem in such situation.

I have used this setup for my apps (both android and iphone) - connecting to a web server app written in php with postgres back-end.